# Proof of Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. What is the dominated function in this case?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral, fourier-transform

I'm reading a proof of Riemann-Lebesgue lemma (about Fourier transform) on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma

This uses DCT but I wonder what is the dominated function.

Let $f\in L^1$, and at the last part of the proof,
$|\widehat f(\xi)|\leqq\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb R}\left|f(x)-f(x+\pi/\xi)\right|dx\to 0$ as $|\xi|\to \infty$ by the continuity of $f$ and DCT.

Of course, $|f(x)-f(x+\pi/\xi)|\to 0$ by the continuity, but I don't know why we can use DCT.

To use DCT, we have to find $F\in L^1$ (independent of $\xi$) s.t. $|f(x)-f(x+\pi/\xi)|\leqq F(x)$ for all $x$.

I have $|f(x)-f(x+\pi/\xi)|\leqq|f(x)|+|f(x+\pi/\xi)|$, and I don't think $|f(x+\pi/\xi)|$ can be dominated by a function independent of $\xi$.

How can I use DCT in this situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of the proof you are looking at assumes that $f$ is continuous *and has compact support*, so there is an interval $[-M,M]$ outside of which $f(x)$ equals zero. And $f$ must be bounded, so put $B:=\sup_{x\in {\mathbb R}}|f(x)|<\infty$. An extremely crude, but integrable, bounding function would be

$$ F(x):=\begin{cases}
B& \text{if $x\in [-M-1, M+1]$}\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
This $F$ is a suitable dominator for $|f(x+\pi/\xi)|$ whenever $|\xi|>\pi$. Remember we only care about bounding the integrand as $|\xi|\to\infty$.